Airflow problem with new fireplace glass doors
New glass fireplace doors seems to be having airflow problems, first fire. Not enough insulation to completely seal door so we added more for a complete seal. Could the complete seal of insulation be prohibiting the fire from staying lit?  Instructions gone.  Bad wood or too much insulation?

These days instructions are typically available on the web.

Photos of what you are doing would help a lot. But from the description:
The fire needs to be able to draw air from somewhere to stay lit, never mind to burn well. If it doesn't have a separate air intake (few do), it draws that air from the room. If you seal the opening, it can't do that.
Most fireplace door sets I've seen have an area at the bottom that acts as an air intake. Some have adjustments which let you adjust how much airflow the fire is getting.

Note that the fact that the fireplace draws air from the room means that it is drawing outside air into the room. And a lot of the heat travels up the chimney or into the stone of the fireplace. This is why fireplaces are generally not very good at heating rooms, though they may heat the area right around the fireplace. Fireplaces that draw combustion air from outside can do better. Improving heat transfer into the room also helps; that's part of why the Franklin stove was so important an invention. (Making cooking safer was the other part.)
